# actionlink based on inheritance asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

Let us say I have 3 classes A, B and C. B and C inherit from A which contains the string field Name.

I have implemented the controllers As, Bs and Cs for each class. I can list all instances of B and C in a view called Index produced by controller As.

The controllers Bs and Cs also have a method Details which spews out a view given the id for an instance of B and C respectively.

I am wondering about the cleanest way to produce action links for the details pages for B and C objects? I could use GetType() and produce the controller name based on this but this seems a bit cumbersome.

Hope this makes sense. Looking forward to hearing from you. Thanks.

Christian

Comment: Let me see if I'm following correctly. You have AController which has an Index() method that is listing all B and C objects and you want to create the action links for these objects so they point to the appropriate Details() method for BController / CController depending on the type?

Comment: @Dismissile yes that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an extension method on your A class that will return the name of the controller:

```
public static class AExtensions
{
    public static string GetControllerName(this A obj)
    {
       // put logic to determine type here
       if( obj is B ) return "BController";
       else if( obj is C ) return "CController";
       else return "AController";

    }
}
```

Then in your view you could have your link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", obj.GetControllerName(), new { id= obj.Id })
```

This method sort of makes me feel dirty but it works I guess.

Comment: sure but that's exactly what I would like to avoid. in the extension method i could place some cases statement which uses GetType() no probs.

Comment: You want to avoid what? The extension method? Using GetType()?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I believe there is a cleaner version than the one you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody needs to make the decision about object type. All that remains is where you do it. If you only have a single list with all of the types in it you can split the list in the controller. Then recombine the types in the view.

```
foreach (var obj in AllObjs)
{
   if (obj.GetType().Equals(typeof(B))
     Model.AllBType.Add(obj);
   else
     Model.AllCType.Add(obj);
}

@foreach (var obj in Model.AllBType)
   Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "BController", new { id = obj.Id });

@foreach (var obj in Model.AllCType)
   Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "CController", new { id = obj.Id });
```

If you create the B and C objects or query for them individually by type why not just keep those results as independent lists in your model.